# Identify specific pattern in .c file or text files using regular expressions python and re.compile

Tags: python, regex

I have a data file as shown below and i need to extract all data in the form of  *V_AD_bs_NOut_Errs = V_AD_bs_NOut_Errs & C_SD_bs_NOxOut_Mask;*. but the regex i have is :`^[a-zA-Z]*_bs_[a-zA-Z0-9] [=] [a-zA-Z]_bs_[a-zA-Z0-9]*[ ]  | [a-zA-Z0-9_]*_bs_[a-zA-Z0-9_;]*|;$'`

could anyone help. im new to this and not really sure of how to get this.

below is the example data.

```
  if ((T_ATM_bs_Enbl & 4194304U) > 0U) {

       */
      P_AD_bs_NO_Out_Errs = P_AD_bs_NO_Out_Errs & C_SCD_bs_NO_Out_Mask;


      V_AD_bs_NOut_Errs = V_AD_bs_NOut_Errs & C_SD_bs_NOxOut_Mask;
    }

      rtb_RelationalOperator_im = ((V_ATD_bs_NOx_Out_Errs &
        C_SCD_bs_NOx_Out_NOxHtrMonMask) > 0U);



        V_SCD_bs_NOtMap = V_SCD_bs_Map | tmp;
      }

        V_1_bs_NO_End = ~(1 << ((uint16_T)
         SENSOR_HTR_RESP_ERR_BIT)) & V_bs_NO_Enbled;

       V_1_bs_NO_End = ~(1 << ((uint16_T)
         SENSOR_HTR_RESP_ERR_BIT)) & V_bs_NO_Enbled;  

       V_1_bs_NO_End = ~(1 << ((uint16_T)
         SENSOR_HTR_RESP_ERR_BIT)) & V_bs_NO_Enbled;
```

````py
errors = []
linenum = 0
pattern = re.compile('^[a-zA-Z]*_bs_[a-zA-Z0-9] [=] [a-zA-Z]_bs_[a-zA-Z0-9]*[ ](&)[ ]|[a-zA-Z0-9_]*_bs_[a-zA-Z0-9_;]*', re.MULTILINE)
with open('test2.c','rt') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        linenum+=1
        if pattern.search(line) != None:
            errors.append((linenum,line.rstrip('\n')))
    for err in errors:
        print("Line " +str(err[0]) + ":" +err[1])
        ```
````

Comment: Are you trying to analyze a programming language with regular expressions? You might be better of using a real parser if this is a continued task.

Comment: so i am trying to pick up all strings that follow this pattern  . it can be in a text file or a .c file . *V_str_bs_str1 = V_str_bs_str1 & C_str2_bs_str3 ;*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just described your regex you want in that comment above.  If you want

```
V_str_bs_str1 = V_str_bs_str1 & C_str2_bs_str3 ;
```

then your regex would look like

```
V_\w+_bs_\w+ = V_\w+_bs_\w+ & C_\w+_bs_\w+ ;
```

Basically, anywhere you have a `str` above, replace it with `\w+`.  However, this requires *exactly* one space between each item. This doesn't have to be true for c code. So to match pieces with extra or wonky spacing, replace whitespace above with `\s+` to match at least one whitespace. I've also added matching whitespace at beginning and end of line.

```
^\s*V_\w+_bs_\w+\s+=\s+V_\w+_bs_\w+\s+&\s+C_\w+_bs_\w+\s*;\s*$
```

Comment: its not working. i tried running but it doesn't pick up any matches

Comment: Hmm. Looking at your original post and not the comment, it looks like your strings have underscores in them. This would actually simplify things because then you could replace `[a-zA-Z0-9]` with just `\w` because `\w` is shorthand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Comment: I updated the answer to include underscores, ran the code with your example input, and it matches _only_ `V_AD_bs_NOut_Errs = V_AD_bs_NOut_Errs & C_SD_bs_NOxOut_Mask;` with some whitespace around it. Is that what you were looking for?